# how can i stop a network application from one node to other using udp port?

Tags: c#

how can i stop a network application from one node who has ipaddress and udp port no of node2, the application is running on node2,

i can also have the application name form node2

i want to stop that application using os calls how is it possible,

i am working in C#

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean stop an application running on system1 from receiving packets (no connections, of course, in UDP) from system2 on a given port.

There are two possibilities:

1. Do the blocking in the network, either have a router block the packets or a firewall (the latter is likely to be easier). Any decent firewall should have a programmatic interface to automate configuration.
2. Receive the packets in the application, and check the source IP address. If the address matches the blocked IP then do no extra processing.

For the latter approach, use one of the receive functions that returns the source IP address. E.g. [`UdpClient.Recieve`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.net.sockets.udpclient.receive) (follow the link for an example).

Comment: i want to terminate the prosess on system2 by sending a OS call from system 1 how is it possible.

Comment: @moon: There are a number of options, WMI might be easiest: has remoting at its core and Win32_Process class and has Terminate method.